# Bind template reference variable as an attribute directive type

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular-directive, angular-template

I'm building an attribute directive that should get several templates which in turn should contain extra data for filtering that would be used later to selected the required template.
So I've extended the TemplatePortalDirective as follows:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[filter]ng-template"
})
export class FilterableTemplateDirective extends TemplatePortalDirective {

  @Input() filter: string;

  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  {
    super(templateRef, viewContainerRef);
  }
}
```

and my attribute directive, named `TemplateSelector` has an `@Input` that is used also as the selector by attribute:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[templateSelector]"
})
...
@Input("templateSelector") templates: FilterableTemplateDirective[]
```

Now, lets assume I have the following template:

```
<div templateSelector="[templateA, templateB]"></div>
<ng-template filter="div[data-type-a]" #templateA>
...
</ng-template>
<ng-template filter="div[data-type-b]" #templateB>
...
</ng-template>
```

So, when I'm trying to access `this.templates` from a method within `TemplateSelector` I'm getting the array, but it's of type `TemplateRef`, that is, plain `ng-template`, with no extra fields, though when I was debugging I've seen that `FilterableTemplateDirective` was constructed twice, before the array with the templates was assigned, and the `filter` also was assigned, though the assignment of filters happened later than the assignment of the array with the templates.
I've tried to cast upon constructing of the array, like so:

```
<div templateSelector="[templateA as FilterableTemplateDirective, templateBtemplateA as FilterableTemplateDirective]"></div>
```

or so:

```
<div templateSelector="[<FilterableTemplateDirective>templateA, <FilterableTemplateDirective>templateBtemplateA]"></div>
```

neither of which succeeded, the app just crashes saying that it was expecting the end of array instead of `as` or the angle brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now it seems that the answer is obvious and was lying on the surface - just to add `exportAs` property on the `Directive decorator`, then to assign the reference to the template reference variable, quite similar to the `ngForm`...

Answer (score 1):

If you have flexibility in your template, then you can achieve what you want using [@ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) as follows:

```
<div templateSelector>
  <ng-template filter="div[data-type-a]">
    ...
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template filter="div[data-type-b]">
    ...
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

and your `templateSelector` directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[templateSelector]"
})

...

@ContentChildren(FilterableTemplateDirective) 
templates: QueryList<FilterableTemplateDirective>;
```

When tagging elements with template variables, you are limited in that you are not able to tell Angular what you want from that element. With template queries such as `@ContentChildren`, `@ContentChild`, `@ViewChild`, and `@ViewChildren`, you have the flexibility in telling Angular if you want a directive/component from it, or `ElementRef`, or `ViewContainerRef` (and maybe some other tokens).

Comment: Yes, definitely an option, but it's less a question of flexibility and more of logic, I would prefer to leave the templates outside of the targeted element if possible...